# Moving pieces in an array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How could you move array characters?????????

Comment: Please post some code. We cannot help you without that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey Coder, welcome to SO! its a good idea to read through some of the documentation, like creating a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you having trouble getting coordinates from a user, or moving a character from one location to another? These two problems are separable, you can -- and should -- solve them independently.

Comment: Your effort would be easier if the User could input the row and column with spaces.  Otherwise you have to read in as a string, then dissect the string.

Comment: I am just having trouble with moving from one place to another. @thomasmatthews yes that's what I'm doing. I will post some code in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some basic code with high-level comments. It is **not exactly** as you desire. But since you have provided some code it is nearly there.

After reading the comments and understanding what is happening, it should be relatively straightforward to modify the below code to your requirements:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArray(int gameboard[5][5]){
  std::cout << "This is what the gameboard looks like now:"  << std::endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
       std::cout << gameboard[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  // Declare array and print what it looks like
  int gameboard[5][5] = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}};
  printArray(gameboard);

  // Get input for which coordinates the user wants to swap
  int row1, column1, row2, column2;
  std::cout << "Please enter the coordinates of the first piece:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Row:";
  std::cin >> row1;
  std::cout << "Column:";
  std::cin >> column1;
  std::cout << "Please enter the coordinates of the second piece:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Row:";
  std::cin >> row2;
  std::cout << "Column:";
  std::cin >> column2;

  // Swap values at provided coordinates by using a temp variable
  int temp = gameboard[row1][column1];
  gameboard[row1][column1] = gameboard[row2][column2];
  gameboard[row2][column2] = temp;
  printArray(gameboard);

  return 0;
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
This is what the gameboard looks like now:
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
Please enter the coordinates of the first piece:
Row: 0
Column: 0
Please enter the coordinates of the second piece:
Row: 4
Column: 4
This is what the gameboard looks like now:
5 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 1
```

**Tasks TO-DO for you:**

- Change `printArray` to allow arrays of varying sizes not just `5 x 5`.
- Ensure user input for `row`, `column` and value are numbers.
- Ensure user input `row`, and `column` values are within the bounds of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much @shash678. What I am trying to do though is move an already existing piece on an array. Here is what I am trying to do:

Comment: cout << "Please enter piece coordinates to move piece: ";
        cin >> row >> col;
        cout << "Enter coordinates to move piece to: ";
        cin >> row1 >> col1;
        gameboard[row1][col1] = gameboard[row][col];

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help.